# Generic Inquiry of discount Percent or Prices

Tags: acumatica

What is the best way to export a list of the current discounts: percent, (price - if possible) and inventory id(s). We currently utilize 2 types of discounts:

- Customer Price Class by item - **Line** - Percent and Quantity
- Customer Price Class by item - **Group** - Percent and Quantity

To give some back story. We produce print catalogs. We would like to know the discounted price. It is helpful to know that the price we are displaying is correct. If finding the price is too complicated. The percent for the given quantity break would be enough (we have max of 3 break quantities). Entering these into a sales order or a quote is an option but we have 980 discount sequence ids.

[Discount Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNSa0.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Terry,
Could you share all of your joins?

Answer (score 0):

I have a GI that I believe will do that or get you close enough to finish...[See if this result looks good for you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnmPm.png)
[if so add these tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k67lb.png)
[Add these relations]

[relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqAl1.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH10y.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqw83.png)

I hope this will help you...

Comment: 1. If there are multiple break quantities what should be done. e.g. [example of two breaks in quanitity](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hkf0ge3dzcj3siu/Discounts.png?dl=0). 2. Can you share all of the joins/relations and their active relations. (i am new to joining, it is tricky not to get duplicate data as the result of a bad join) thanks again